# jQuery - array from multiple sources

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out how to create JSON object from multiple sources. 
I mean, multiple fields and dropdowns, one input for multiple files, and below each file one dropdown with size, second one with quantity and another one with paper type.

I need to put all this information about each file in object like this:

```
{
  "files": [
    {"file_name" : "file1", "size" : "10x10", "quantity" : 1, "paper" : "glossy"},
    {"file_name" : "file2", "size" : "10x10", "quantity" : 4, "paper" : "glossy"},
    {"file_name" : "file3", "size" : "20x30", "quantity" : 3, "paper" : "glossy"},
    {"file_name" : "file4", "size" : "30x40", "quantity" : 6, "paper" : "glossy"},
    {"file_name" : "file5", "size" : "20x30", "quantity" : 2, "paper" : "glossy"},
  ]
}
```

I have code, but it doesn't work, because of two different arrays. I've tried to push data in one array but structure of result object is wrong.

```
    function addToPhotoArray() {
        PhotoArray = [];
        var items = $('input[name*=files]')[0].files;
        var filesLength = $('input[name*=files]')[0].files.length;
        if (filesLength > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                var fileName = items[i].name;
                PhotoArray.push({ name: fileName });
                console.log(fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    function addToCountArray() {
        CountArray = [];
        $('.photo_count option:selected').each(function(){
            CountArray.push({ photo_count: $(this).val() });
        });
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

Is this better ?

```
var jsonArr = [];
var json = "[]";

function createJson(){
    jsonArr = JSON.parse(json);

    $(".file_container").each(function(index, container){
        if($(container).find("input[type='file']").val() != ''){
            jsonArr.push(new File(
                $(container).find("input[type='file']").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''),
                $(container).find("select#size").val(),
                $(container).find("select#count").val(),
                $(container).find("select#paper").val()
            ));
        }
    });


    json = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
}

function File(file_name, size, quantity, paper){ //class
        this.file_name = file_name;
    this.size = size;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.paper = paper;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, or I don't fully understand your code. I've tried to use this code in JSFiddle and quantity remains 0; but it's not main problem. I'm trying to understand, how to fill this JSON object (initially it's empty) with data from file container. Here's an example fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cheslavcc/x8fmfefe/)

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you!